# Jasmine Javascript Unit-testing appending HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jasmine

I have the following Jasmine test,

```
describe('test', function () {

    beforeEach(function() {  
        loadFixtures('../../Fixtures.html'); 
    });

    it('should add some html', function () {  

        $("#some_btn").click(); 

        expect($("#some_div")).toExist();        
    });

   it('should do something with the div', function () {  

        //do something

        expect($("#some_div")).toHaveClass("some_class");         
    });
});
```

Triggering the click will execute a function, witch will add a div to the html page,

```
function addDiv(){
    $("#existing_div").append('<div id="some_div"></div>');
}
```

this is the html,

```
...
<div id="some_btn" onclick="addDiv();"></div>
...
<div id="existing_div">
    <!--where the div is supposed to be inserted-->
</div>
```

The second test fails.
I'm new to Jasmine is this suppose to fail? am i missing something?

thanks..

Edited: I edited the code, i had copied it wrong, was missing the last part of the test. Sorry :(

Comment: What mechanism is supposed to invoke that function?

Comment: We'll need more code to help

Comment: Also you don't need to construct the event like that: `$('#some_btn').click();` will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks Pointy i didn't know that, the example i found was like that

Comment: did you put a break point and ensured that you are indeed appending #some_div? the test may be failing b/c your code actually doesn't work

Comment: yes the code does work, the div is added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you load the fixture every time before you run a single spec the second spec must fail cause it click was never fired and function that appends the div was nerver executed for this spec.

Comment: How can i load the fixture only once? Or do i have to do all the steps in every test?

Comment: I think this would be the wrong way. Just fire the click event in every spec, or in the before function.

Answer (score 0):

try putting your `loadFixtures('../../Fixtures.html');` in `beforeAll` block instead of `beforeEach`.